# Does simply-connected imply measurable?

Tags: geometry, measure-theory

The famous examples of [non-measurable sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-measurable_set) involve a sophisticated selections of points from a ball (or another object). This raises the following question: if a certain object in a Euclidean space is simply-connected, does it imply that it is Lebesgue-measurable?

(BACKGROUND: I am doing a geometry-related research, where most shapes are simple polygons and circles. But when I try to extend the results to more general shapes, I keep running into problems related to measurability. So, I want to know if assuming that my shapes are simply-connected will save me from this trouble).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply connected sets can be nonmeasurable.
Let $E\subset[0,1]$ be a nonmeasurable set and let $A=E\times[0,1]\cup[0,1]\times\{0\}$.
If you draw a picture, you see that $A$ resembles a comb and is connected and simply connected.
The set $A$ is not measurable.
([This MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329992/how-to-show-product-of-two-nonmeasurable-sets-is-nonmeasurable) might be worth a look for the last fact.)

Comment: Thanks! What about the *open* simply connected shapes - are they measurable?

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi, open sets are always measurable for a Borel measure. (And the Lebesgue measure is a Borel measure.)

Comment: OK, thanks. So I can just consider all open sets, whether connected or not.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi, yes, you can safely consider all open and closed sets, independent of connectedness.