# Cartesian Product of (Lebesgue) Non-measurable Sets (without referring to Product Measure)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ be a nonmeasurable set, and let $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be a (Lebesgue) measurable set.

How do we show that the Cartesian product $A\times E$ is nonmeasurable in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Is there any way to show it **without referring to the concept of product measure**? I can understand ([How to show product of two nonmeasurable sets is nonmeasurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329992/how-to-show-product-of-two-nonmeasurable-sets-is-nonmeasurable)) but would like a more concrete method. Perhaps using Caratheodory criterion or something like that?

Thanks for any help. Hope the question makes sense..

Comment: What you mean under nonmeasurability in $R^2$:  the set does not belong a) to $L(R)\times L(R)$  or  b) to the completion of the class   $L(R)\times L(R)$ w.r.t. two dimensional Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Good question, I suppose it is (b), otherwise if (a) it is trivial right?

Comment: Under  (b)  your assertion  is not  valit: Let $A \subset R$ be a nonmeasurable set and $E$ be a measurable set of Lebesgue measure zero. Then $A \times E$ is measurable.

Comment: @George I see.. If $E$ has nonzero measure then is it valid?

Comment: Yes, $A \times E$ will be nonmeasurable..

Comment: I'm not sure if this last statement is necessarily correct.  But definitely all subsets of a null set are null (by definition of the Lebesgue measure)