# Non-lebesgue measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Find Lebesgue measurable sets $A,B\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $A+B$ is not Lebesgue measurable

How would I go about constructing this?
I'm at a lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose any nonmeasurable set $S\subset \mathbb{R}$. Define $A = S\times\{0\}$ and $B = \{0\}\times S$. Then, $A+B = S\times S$, [which is nonmeasurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329992/how-to-show-product-of-two-nonmeasurable-sets-is-nonmeasurable) even though $A$ and $B$ both have measure $0$.

Comment: Can this be done for $\mathbb R$? Two measureable sets such that when you add their elements create a nonmeasurable set? Seems to not be possible to me, intuitively. Seems like this idea is generalizable to any dimension 2 or greater, yes? Just have a nonmeasureable set in a lower dimension that is thus measure zero in the higher dimension.

Comment: I'd have to think a bit about $\mathbb{R}$. Yes, this should be generalizable to spaces of higher dimension.

Comment: It appears that the answer to the question in $\mathbb{R}$ is [yes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19471/is-the-sum-of-2-lebesgue-measurable-sets-measurable), although the construction is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for finding that solution! I'm going to have to think about that as it is very counter intuitive! However, the fact that the cantor set added to itself creates an interval helps me to see why the operation of set addition with infinite sets can do weird things.

Answer (score 2):

Try solving this yourself first before looking at the full answer. Here's a hint:

All null sets are Lebesgue measurable, but $A$ and $B$ may be null sets while $A+B$ may not be null.

> Let $\mathscr{N} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a non-Lebesgue measurable set. Let $A = \mathscr{N}\times \{0\}$ and $B = \{0\}\times [0,1]$. Then $A+B = \mathscr{N}\times [0,1]$ is not Lebesgue measurable. To prove this, it's relatively simple to show that the outer Lebesgue measure of $C\times [0,1]$ for any $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is equal to the outer Lebesgue measure of $C$. Use this to show directly that $A+B$ is not Lebesgue measurable.

edit: fixed a minor mistake